# format the number of digits in results R

Tags: r, decimal, extract, digits, term-document-matrix

I created a document term matrix that searches numbers from `100000 to 600000` for  some data mining issues, but i mentioned that it doesn't take as results the wanted numbers  it combine every numbers with spaces or decimal in a 6 digit combination and returns it as a single number

this is my code

```
    library(text2vec)

 docs = c(doc1 = " letter ltetter (-è)  323.456 1  789 ",
     dc2 = "letters 123.45 1letters 100000  98 76 54  ",
     dc3 = "123456789  454321 letters 124 258 ")
#delete every thing but numbers
    docs = gsub("[^0-9 ]", "", docs, perl = T)
#creating the dtm
    itoken = itoken(docs, tokenizer = word_tokenizer, ids = names(docs))
    vector = create_vocabulary(itoken)
    vectorizer = vocab_vectorizer(vector)
    dtm = create_dtm(itoken, vectorizer)

     (dtm[, colnames(dtm) %in% 100000:600000])
3 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
     100000  454321 323456
doc1      .     .      1
dc2       1     .      .
dc3       .     1      .
```

the `100000` extracted **is correct**= it is in the wanted margin `(100000 and 600000)`

the `454321` **is correct**= it is in the wanted margin `(100000 and 600000)`

the `323456` **is false**= the number in the document is **323.456** it **is not in the margin**, but extracted
how can I adapt it to return just number from `100000 to 600000`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your code indeed appears to return just numbers from 100000 to 600000. Also, you should replace `create_dtm(it, vectorizer)` with `create_dtm(itoken, vectorizer)`.

Comment: i want to extract numbers from `100000` to `600000` but the code returns each **combination of 6 terms** even if there is a comma in between. it returns this `123.456` as a 6 digit number but it is not

Answer (score 1):

You can search for a word boundary `\\b` with 6 digits start with a number from 1-6 `[1-6]` followed by any 5 digits `[0-9]{5}`

```
library(stringr)
docs_list <- lapply(docs, 
                   function(x){str_extract_all(x,"\\b[1-6][0-9]{5}\\b", simplify = TRUE)})

docs_list[sapply(docs_list, function(x) length(x)==0L)] <- NA

unlist(docs_list)
doc1      dc2      dc3 
  NA "100000" "454321"
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to extract all numbers from the documents, including decimal points.

So you want to do something like

```
docs <- sapply(docs, function(doc) {
  nums <- regmatches(doc, gregexpr("[0-9]+\\.*[0-9]*", doc))
  paste(unlist(nums), collapse = " ")
})
docs
#                       doc1                        dc2 
#            "323.456 1 789" "123.45 1 100000 98 76 54" 
#                        dc3 
# "123456789 454321 124 258"
```

If we run the rest of your code on `docs`:

```
library(text2vec)
itoken = itoken(docs, tokenizer = word_tokenizer, ids = names(docs))
vector = create_vocabulary(itoken)
vectorizer = vocab_vectorizer(vector)
dtm = create_dtm(itoken, vectorizer)
dtm[, colnames(dtm) %in% 100000:600000]
# 3 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#      454321 100000
# doc1      .      .
# dc2       .      1
# dc3       1      .
```

Comment: no sir I want the opposit. i just want numbers from 1 million to 6 millions the decimal numbers extracted are false (they are not in the wanted margin)

Comment: I want to rectify the problem of extraction decimals

Comment: Isn't that what I did? If you process `docs` as I showed, and run the rest of your code, you won't have the decimal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider the decimal point in the gsub function.

```
library(text2vec)

docs = c(doc1 = " letter ltetter (-è)  323.456 1  789 ",
     dc2 = "letters 123.45 1letters 100000  98 76 54  ",
     dc3 = "123456789  454321 letters 124 258 ")

#If you have decimal commas first do this
docs = sub(',','.',docs,perl = T)
#Here what i've changed
docs = gsub("[^0-9^.^ ]", "", docs, perl = T)

#creating the dtm
itoken = itoken(docs, tokenizer = word_tokenizer, ids = names(docs))
vector = create_vocabulary(itoken)
vectorizer = vocab_vectorizer(vector)
dtm = create_dtm(itoken, vectorizer)
dtm_1 <- as.numeric(colnames(dtm))
table <- as.matrix(dtm[, (dtm_1 < 600000 & dtm_1>10000)])

library(reshape)
df_melted <- melt(table)
df_melted <- df_melted[which(df_melted$value != 0),]
colnames(df_melted) <- c("Document","Number Found","times")
```

This gives you:

```
  Document Number Found times
2      dc2       100000     1
6      dc3       454321     1
```

Comment: and if there is a decimal comma ? how can i add it

Comment: Look the code. First, for handle the decimal comma I've added a step before the gsub step. Also, we were comparing only with integer values (we weren't including decimal numbers in the comparison), so I modified slightly the code. Now it should work fine.